# std::string_view vs std::string

Tags: c++, строки, view

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

using std::literals::string_view_literals::operator""sv;
using std::literals::string_literals::operator""s;

int main()
{
    std::string_view name_sv = "text"sv;
    std::string name_s = "text"s;

    std::cout << name_sv << std::endl;
    std::cout << name_s << std::endl;
}
```

Я понимаю, что std::string_view хранит только указатель и длину, без владения. Но объясните пожалуйста, в чем состоит принципиальное различие (**в этом коде**) между объявлениями переменных `name_sv` и `name_s`? Различие только в методах? Или будут различия в хранении, продолжительности жизни и т.п.?

Comment: Непонятно, откуда этот вопрос, если *"Я понимаю, что std::string_view хранит только указатель и длину, без владения."*

Comment: В этом примере для std::string может выделяться динамическая память а для std::string_view - нет

Comment: string_view - только для чтения. Т.е. в name_s вы можите поменять символ `name_s[0]='b'`, а в name_sv - нет. Отказ от модификации, позволяет отказаться от лишниго копирования содержимого и выделения памяти под копию.